# AppendChild causing inner HTML of another node to disappear

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript creating a number of DOM nodes, so that the nodes can have various animation functions assigned to them.  The animation functions are called by a range of other functions.

I have a situation where calling new on an object is removing inner HTML from previously created objects.  Using the debugger, I tracked this to a call to appendChild.  Before the call, the inner HTML is there, after, it is gone.  This is killing me.

Here is the HTML source:

```
//modeler.html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="modeler.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="drawer.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modeler.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="drawer.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var modeler, thing, leftDrawer, rightDrawer;

    modeler = new Modeler;

    thing = document.createElement('div');
    thing.innerHTML = 'hello world';

    leftDrawer = new Drawer('leftDrawer', 'left', thing);
    rightDrawer = new Drawer('rightDrawer', 'right', thing);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above, note `leftDrawer` and `rightDrawer` are both assigned a new `Drawer`. It is after the assignment of `rightDrawer` that the problem occurs.

```
// modeler.js

function Modeler () {
  var modeler = document.createElement('div');
  modeler.id = 'modeler';
  document.body.appendChild(modeler);
};
```

'modeler' is the main containing element.

Stepping through with the debugger shows that the inner HTML of the node created by `leftDrawer = new Drawer` is present, but when `rightDrawer = new Drawer` is called, the inner HTML of the node created by `leftDrawer` is deleted.

```
// drawer.js

function Drawer (id, side, contents) {
  var drawer;

  this.id = id;
  this.side = side.toLowerCase();

  drawer = document.createElement('div');
  drawer.className = 'drawer' + ' ' + 'drawer' + (side[0].toUpperCase() + side.slice(1));
  drawer.id = id;

  if (contents) {
    drawer.appendChild(contents); // After this point, the inner HTML disappears 
  } else {
    console.log('No content given to Drawer');
  };

  document.getElementById('modeler').appendChild(drawer);
};
```

The final HTML contained within the `modeller` div looks like this:

```
<div class="drawer drawerLeft" id="leftDrawer"></div>
<div class="drawer drawerRight" id="rightDrawer">
  <div>hello world</div>
</div>
```

Where it should look like this:

```
<div class="drawer drawerLeft" id="leftDrawer">
  <div>hello world</div>
</div>
<div class="drawer drawerRight" id="rightDrawer">
  <div>hello world</div>
</div>
```

Why is the inner HTML disappearing from the previously created elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `contents` is the same for `leftDrawer` and `rightDrawer`.

Therefore, if you append it twice, it will me moved but not copied.

You must copy it yourself:

```js
drawer.appendChild(contents.cloneNode(true));
```

```js
function Modeler () {
    var modeler = document.createElement('div');
    modeler.id = 'modeler';
    document.body.appendChild(modeler);
}

function Drawer (id, side, contents) {
    var drawer;
    this.id = id;
    this.side = side.toLowerCase();
    drawer = document.createElement('div');
    drawer.className = 'drawer' + ' ' + 'drawer' + (side[0].toUpperCase() + side.slice(1));
    drawer.id = id;
    if (contents)
        drawer.appendChild(contents.cloneNode(true));
    else
        console.log('No content given to Drawer');
    document.getElementById('modeler').appendChild(drawer);
}

var modeler = new Modeler,
  thing = document.createElement('div');
thing.innerHTML = 'hello world';
var leftDrawer = new Drawer('leftDrawer', 'left', thing),
  rightDrawer = new Drawer('rightDrawer', 'right', thing);
```

Comment: Brilliant.  I had not realised this was the case. +1 for you.